# In AWS API Gateway - how do i set stage variables for the test-invoke-stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When I invoke my API from the AWS Console, I notice that the stage name is "test-invoke-stage".

I set up some stage variables to have my mapping send to my lambda function but those values are coming in blank.    When I try to set up the test-invoke-stage so that i can set the variables for that tester, it says I can't name a stage name with the `-` in it .

So how do i use the test invoker and pass in stage variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time 12/2015 - its not available - the question was answered in a webinar with Amazon.  They said it is a feature on their roadmap.  When i see it, I'll update this question/answer.

Update - its now available to add in values for stageVariables when you do the testing in the web console. (2016-01-14)

Comment: Can you give any more detail as to where to declare the stage variables? On the Test screen, I have a section for Stage Variables that says "No stage variables exist for this method" but I cannot find where to declare them!

Comment: Sure, in the API Gateway interface choose stages (they just changed the interface again and probably will in the future - so just look around for the stages.  If you don't have one yet - create a stage... then you should find a section/tab call stage variables. You can add one there.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I already have existing stages, with existing stage variables defined. They work just fine once I've deployed the API. But when I'm using the Test screen in the console, there is no option to use stage variables. Or rather, there is a section there, but it claims "no stage variables exist for this method". I'm assuming it must only work in the Test section for things like Lambda function names, mapping expressions, etc., and not "free variables" that get passed to the method integration (Lambda in this case).

Comment: not sure what you mean by free variables, but if you are talking about stuff passed in from the API itself you should just be able to set the message body or query params

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Either I am completely missing something, or it just doesn't do what I want to do right now. I'll just open a new question if I keep having trouble with it, because I don't want to waste any more of your time, and I think I'll need more room than a comment provides to do the question justice. Thanks!

Comment: @justinpawela - I don't think you're missing it. I am in the same situation. I am using $context.stage to get the stage name. This isn't a stage variable. Not sure how to set that when testing the API via the console...

Comment: It is available only when there is a stage created as part of deployment, how can stage variables be setup when exercising "Test" from the method test page of Console? The answer is a hack, grab the call from dev console and add the stage variable yourself.

Comment: This answer doesn't resolve the issue of how to add stage variables to a test invocation.  In my case I have a `${stageVariables.MY_VARIABLE}` defined in the lambda name, and that single variable shows up in the web console test page with an input where I can enter the value.  But other stage variables necessary to run my script (which are defined in my various stages) don't show up with inputs.

Comment: @MuraliVP how do you grab the call from the dev console?

Comment: My workaround was to have default values that I use when the stage variables are not present.  You could hard-code these into your Lambda, get them from the environment, etc.  Something like: `event['stageVariables'].get('MY_VAR', os.environ.get('DEFAULT_MY_VAR'))`

Comment: I ended up using hard-coded values when staging variables were not available.  Unfortunate that the test console UI doesn't all allow you to declare staging variables like the Lambda console does for the function body.